# Python regex to exclude several words

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I try to search for URLS and want to exclude some. In the variable download_artist I stored  the base  URL and wanto to find additional  links, but not upload, favorites, followers or listens.

So I tried different versions with the mentioned words and  a |. Like:

```
urls = re.findall(rf'^{download_artist}uploads/|{download_artist}^favorites/|^{download_artist}followers/|^{download_artist}listens/|{download_artist}\S+"', response.text, re.IGNORECASE)
```

or:

```
urls = re.findall(rf'{download_artist}^uploads/|^favorites/|^followers/|^listens/|\S+"', response.text, re.IGNORECASE)
```

But it ignores my ^ for excluding the words. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Please post a minimal working example and show the values of any variables interpolated.   Please show the expected result and also the actual result.

Comment: `^` has two meanings within regex: 1) The start of the string, and 2) to exclude individual characters in a character class.  You can't use it to exclude words.  However, you can remove them in python, e.g. `urls = [url for url in urls if not url.search(r'uploads|favorites|followers|listens')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

^ only works as a negation in character classes inside [], outside it represents the beginning of the input.

I suggest you do two matches: One to match all urls and another one to match the ones to exclude. Then remove the second set of urls from the first one.

That will keep the regexes simple and readable.

If you have to do it in one regex for whatever reason you can try to solve it with (negative) lookaround pattern (see https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need use "lookaround" in this case, can see more details in https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.

So, i think wich this regex solve your problem:

`{download_artist}(?!uploads/|favorites/|followers/|listens/)\S+\"`

You can test if regex working in https://regex101.com/. This site is very useful when you work with regex.